# Launching VSCode from terminal keeps posting state updates

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like to navigate to my working dir via GitBash and upon launching VSCode via

```
code .
```

the terminal locks up in the process and I have to launch another GitBash to execute my commands. I am having troubles figuring out why its behaving like this since its happening only on 1 out of 3 machines I'm using. Google is so far no luck.

How can I change this to the default behavior I'm used to? On the other two machines it just launches VSCode in the directory where I am at and prompts to a new line to accept further cli commands.

[Set State updates VSCode img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3NAJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem, the issue was in the PATH environment variable. It pointed to Code.exe in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code

it is supposed to point to

C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin